# C linking C++ static functions

Tags: c++, c, extern

my question is somewhat simple;

Is it possible to do C linking (`extern "C"`) on C++ static class functions? - Without using wrappers.

Comment: Since those functions are scoped, you can't avoid mangling the class name into there. You can however, achieve the same effect with a friend function, I think.

Comment: Uhm, the issue is that I want to call a C++ static function from assembly, and I hoped to go without a stupid C++ wrapper function.

Comment: if you have control over the class declaration, then you can use the workaround I described bellow. Same net effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't but simply write a wrapper function.

```
class X
{
public:
    static void f();
};

extern "C" void call_X_f()
{
    X::f();
}
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to avoid, the wrapper that is.

Comment: @Skeen Put that in your question.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments, you can't. But you can achieve the same net effect.

Here's what I was talking about:

```
class A;
extern "C" void foo(A*);


class A
{
    int i;
    friend void foo(A*);
};

extern "C" void foo (A* a)
{
    a->i = 10;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    foo(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles fine on gcc 4.7.2 [here](http://ideone.com/IMont8)

Comment: This solution will allow me to keep protection on `int i` right?

Comment: I cannot see how this relates to the question.

Comment: Just being curious, that's all

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it's the alternative I mentioned in the comments to the question. I put a bit more context in the answer now.

Comment: @Skeen, Yes, in this code sample, `i` is private. In fact, even `foo` being a friend is kept private.

Comment: I still don't see any evidence of static class functions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, because a static class function cannot be specified to have C linkage, that's what the OP asked about. But I guessed, that all they want is to access the classes private members inside the function. Hence the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

`extern "C"` can't be applied to a static member function. But since the goal is to call the function from assembler, just use the mangled name in the assembler code. There's nothing magic here; all you need is the name.

Comment: Wouldn't that severly break portability across different compilers, as mangling schemes are different?

Comment: @Skeen - calling functions from assembler is inherently not portable, so, no, it doesn't break anything that currently works.

Comment: Well isn't it less portable than calling a simple c function?